# use of undeclared identifier 'GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY'

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d

Anyone please help me .i am working on sneakyjoystick class when i import these class some error are identified they are following :-

**use of undeclared identifier 'GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY'**

**use of undeclared identifier 'GL_COLOR_ARRAY'**

Comment: This is a difference between OpenGL 1.0 and 2.0 - OpenGL ES1.0 has those defined in the gl.h header but OpenGL ES2.0 does not. I'm working through this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3857/how-to-create-dynamic-textures-with-ccrendertexture but ran into the same problem. I'll update my answer if I can find out how to do this with OpenGL 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY` and `GL_COLOR_ARRAY` are usually defined in `gl.h`

> **/usr/include/GL $** grep GL_COLOR_ARRAY gl.h -rn
>
> 209:#define GL_COLOR_ARRAY    0x8076

Are you including this header correctly?

If you paste a bit of your code we can probably give you a more detailed answer.